# Page cache - initiate the first page request in the server

Tags: asp.net, caching, outputcache

I'm implementing Outputcache in my application and it works fine, but the first time always take a lot to load and the next following request will be faster...

I would like to know if there is a way to initiate the page caching on the server side and serve the cached page upon the very first request, rather than have it triggered by the user one first time.

Any ideas/suggestions will be very much welcome.

Best regards,
TT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the IIS Warm up module, you can configure the pages it will invoke which then when you deploy your new site it will cause the page cache to be built.

[Now Available: The IIS 7.5 Application Warm-Up Module](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2009/10/14/now-available-the-iis-7-5-application-warm-up-module.aspx)

Another feature to consider is in .NET 4.0 you can make the OutputCache be disk based which will allow the cache to persist between the app pool being reset, you may want to consider this in addition to the warm up module.

Comment: Learned about both of these at DevConnections a couple days ago!